# PS3 Media server Lag

Tags: wireless-networking, ps3, media-server, ps3-media-server

I'm running the PS3 Media Server(1.90.1) on Windows 8.1 Wired/Wifi but I have some problem when I want to share 1080p(MKV) Movies. The film is lagging when I want to see the movie. I have a “good” pc (Intel core i3-2100 3.1GHz, 8gb ram, 1gb Videocard). How can I see full HD movies in my PS3 without lag? Do you know a better program for sharing and transcoding?
Please help me.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by “lag”. Uneven playback speed? Stuttering? Artifacts/picture corruption? Audio/video out of sync?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the number of cores used by ps3 media server to 2 (two). After that everything went fine.

Here's the image of want I've changed: 
[image: PS3 Settings]

- Set buffer size to 300
- Changed CPU threads to 2
- Set Transcoding quality (MPEG-2) to Automatic (Wireless)

After that I was able to serve a 1080p movie without trouble.

Comment: Can you explain how to accomplish that, and share some insight on why that would solve the problem?  Thanks.

Comment: How many cores was it before you changed it?

Answer (score -1):

It may depend on the connection and to my results, There is no such program for PS3 just it's built in. Instead for using the built-in Media Server(talking about pc), I recommend to use Tv-Mobili because it is much faster.